# Paginated chunk of bigger resultset *and* total resultset count in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My personal holy grail of SQL (specifically MySQL) query building is this:

I wonder if / how it is possible to - in the same query - to get a paginated chunk of a bigger resultset (ie. page 2, with 20 per page, of 13000 total results) *and* the count of total results (in this example 13000).

I'm not saying that this is the best or most efficient way to get the two results (page of results and total result count) but I like a challenge and can never seem to do this in one query.

So, what do you say?